# Average Deviation of Cards

Tags: statistics, variance, central-limit-theorem, standard-deviation, card-games

Suppose we draw cards from a standard 52 card deck where each card has a value from 1-13 (Ace being 1 King being 13). What is the average deviation of the value of a randomly selected card? What is the average of the sum of 3 randomly selected cards?

> The expected value of a given card is 7. Thus average deviation will be $\frac{1(0) + 2(1) + 2(2) + ... + 2(6)}{13} =\frac{42}{13}$. I am assuming average deviation is similar to standard deviation such that for $n$ instances we would scale by $\sqrt{n}$ so average deviation of sum of 3 cards we get $\frac{42\sqrt{3}}{13}$ Is this correct?

Comment: The standard deviation is rhe root of the sum of the **squared** differences.

Comment: Deviation from $7$ or from the sample mean? Sampling with or without replacement? Average absolute deviation or standard deviation?

Comment: Deviation from 7 with 1 card and 21 with 3 cards, without replacement, and average absolute deviation. @Henry

Comment: So your $\frac{42}{13}$ is correct on that basis: note that the denominator which is a divisor of $52$.  For three cards without replacement, the answer will also be rational with a denominator which is a divisor of $52 \times 51 \times 50$ and clearly $\frac{42\sqrt{3}}{13}$ is not rational.

Comment: If instead you were looking at the standard deviation, with one card it would be $\sqrt{14}$, and for the sum of three cards with replacement it would be $\sqrt{14} \times \sqrt{3}$

Comment: Brute force suggests that for three cards without replacement, the mean absolute deviation is $\frac{438}{85}\approx 5.153$ while $\frac{42\sqrt{3}}{13} \approx 5.596$